Cancel calendar sharing with coworker
I was on vacation a week ago, so I shared my schedule with my colleagues. Now I work normally, so I want to know how to make my colleagues invisible to my calendar.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

From the Ribbon bar, choose Share Calendar. In the Calendar Properties dialog, go to the Permissions tab. Click the person you shared your calendar with, and then select Remove, or change the radio button in the bottom section to None.


Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.
